# SkiaSharp make a bitmap on a path clickable

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp, xamarin-forms-4

i have drawn a circle path and for every 1 degree angle am adding a bitmap. Now, i want to listen to each bitmap clicks on that Circle path using Xamarin forms!How can i achieve this.
I have followed manipulating [touches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch) on xamarin and amble to get touch coordinates but unable to get exactly which bitmap is selected?

**EDIT:**

```
 foreach (var item in bitmapPoints)
  {
    using (Stream streami = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resID))
    {
      redBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(streami);
    }
      canvas.DrawBitmap(redBitmap,item, null);
  }
```

Now am trying to enable click event for each bitmap drawn on Canvas. Should i make custom BitMap class having HiTest method? if so, what should be the Rect x and y to be passed to get HiTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is called "Hit Testing" - Xamarin has a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch) in their SkiaSharp docs

```
public bool HitTest(SKPoint location)
{
    // Invert the matrix
    SKMatrix inverseMatrix;

    if (Matrix.TryInvert(out inverseMatrix))
    {
        // Transform the point using the inverted matrix
        SKPoint transformedPoint = inverseMatrix.MapPoint(location);

        // Check if it's in the untransformed bitmap rectangle
        SKRect rect = new SKRect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        return rect.Contains(transformedPoint);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Jason thanks for the information, but the "rect"`s bitmap should be different for each bitmap right? Eg: if i touch on 9th bitmap i need to get its ID and so on! Now should i call HitTest ForEach bitmap drawn ?

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly what you need to do

Comment: great! but my problem is with understanding the Rect here, as shown in code snippet rect always starts at (0,0) which is not the case with me also my 100 bitmaps are the same having exactly same width and height but varies in their ID`s. could you pls provide me any such similar demo source, greatly appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: I linked to an extensive article that has complete source code.  It even has an example with multiple bitmaps. Further, if all your bitmaps are laid out in a pattern you may be able to do some simple geometry to figure this out

Comment: Its a very informative resource link, just updated my question too! A Bow.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/master/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/Transforms/TouchManipulationBitmap.cs

Comment: tried the same way but unable to get the bitmap`s Rect value to find if it is containing the touch point

Comment: How are you able to draw a bitmap on the screen without knowing it’s x,y location?

Comment: i have its x and y location points for all bitmaps, but what am not able to get is the bound rectangle for that bitmap, so as to check if it lies within the bound rectangle. Eg: if bitmap is drawn at x=20,y=100, HitTest(skpoint(20,100)) giving false. X & Y value is generated using following logic.    
    float x = center.X + scaledRadius * (float)Math.Sin(radians);
    float y = center.Y + scaledRadius * (float)Math.Cos(radians);

Comment: if you are not using any translations you should be able to just use rect.Contains() for the hit test

Comment: A Very Big thank you Jason for guiding me. Am not doing any translations but drawing on canvas in a spiral way as explained above. i have drawn bitmap@ {X=156.9795, Y=762.7694} and using new rect(156.9795, 762.7694,bit.width,bit.height) or new rect(0,0,ht,wd).
Now rect.Contains(156.9795,762.7694) returning false in hittest.i tried converting to pixels also but no luck. am stuck in **generating the rect for the bitmap given the point at which its drawn**.  could you assist me on getting a bounding rectangle for a   bitmap of width 50 and height 50 provided a point that will be in bounds rect ?

Comment: public SKRect (float left, float top, float right, float bottom);

Comment: to clarify the point am drawing on canvas is {X=156.9795, Y=762.7694} but when i click the drawn bitmap center am getting {X=66.3333282470703, Y=269.053329467773} is this correct or should i convert Xamarin Point to SKPoint to get correct HitTest. Also, sorry if its a very basic question if i have a coordinates {X=53, Y=272} for left touch of bitmap how can i get float left value from these coordinates?